# Is there any Rhodes local storage like android have Shared Preference

Tags: android, rhodes

I want to store login details on Rhodes. What should I do? Is there one like Android Shared Preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store values as

```
Rho::RhoConfig.user_name = @params['user_name']
Rho::RhoConfig.user_pass = @params['user_pass']
```

Then you can access these values as

```
@user = Rho::RhoConfig.user_name if Rho::RhoConfig.exists?('user_name')
@pass = Rho::RhoConfig.user_pass if Rho::RhoConfig.exists?('user_pass')
```

See more details at official Rhodes docs:
http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodesapi/rhoconfig-api

Answer (score 0):

You can store any piece of data (no need to synchronize) through the use of the local database access api (Rhom):
[Using the Local Database with Rhom](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/rhom)

Comment: how to Strore the login details and the response come from the server ,please give me some example how to save.

Comment: There are examples in the link I provided, look for "save". You need to define your own object that matches the profile information and how that matches what you have in your server. I can't do that for you as it depends completely on what your server returns and what information you care to keep.